# Store only integer value from sql select

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to get only integer value (serial id) without a column name, which makes it a string. I am working in Laravel so I can use Laravel functions for SQL queries if necessary.

```
$idcko = DB::table('repairs')
         ->select('id')
         ->latest();
```

So when I print `idcko` I get something like `{"column name": 2}`
Where I want only number `2`.

UPDATE:

With help of answers, I came up with this idea:

```
$idcko = DB::table('repairs')
                                ->select('id')
                                ->orderBy('id','desc')
                                ->first()
                                ->id;
```

Because I was getting error that I don't have a timestamp column and I wanted to get the newest / highest `id`, I could do a little trick and order it by `id` and select only first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`latest()` just adds an order by clause and returns the builder instance. ([See the API reference](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_latest).) You still need to use some fetch method to actually get any records to pull values from. Since you're trying to get a single value, you can use `first()` and then get the property you want from that record.

```
$id = DB::table('repairs')->select('id')->latest()->first()->id;
```

Comment: For both answers (Samsquanch), I am getting this error: `Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "created_at" does not exist
LINE 1: select "id" from "repairs" order by "created_at" desc limit ...
^ (SQL: select "id" from "repairs" order by "created_at" desc limit 1)`

Comment: Yeah, `latest()` depends on you having a timestamp column. It uses `created_at` by default, but you can pass a different one if your timestamp column is differently named.

Comment: But I did not change name of it. Is there another way how to get the newest `id` if its `serial` type?

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood what you're trying to do. Can you edit the question to add more context/details regarding your overall goal?

Comment: I have updated my question where I posted my solution with your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

You're just wanting to retrieve the value of the column, so use [`value()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results):

```
$idcko = DB::table('repairs')
             ->select('id')
             ->latest()
             // ->first()      // get the first result -- may not be needed?
             ->value('id'); // or any other column name here
```

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about value(). That's better.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for the tip on `first()`, I thought `latest()` returned a single result.

Comment: I think you were right at first. I believe `->value('id')` is a shortcut equivalent to `->first()->id`

Comment: Guys, for both of your's answers, I get same error as I mentioned in comment in @Don'tPanic answer.

Comment: @Ady96 are you sure the column you're trying to select is in the `repairs` table?

Comment: @Samsquanch yes. In `repairs` table is only its `id` and one more column.

Comment: Is the other column `created_at`? `latest()` uses that column by default, so if it's not there that could be causing your issue.